# Custom HTML in Rich Text Fields

Tags: entry, field, richtext, dashboard

I've noticed the `HTML` option above Rich Text Fields for entries is now gone in Craft 2.5, regardless of being configured as `Default`, `Simple`, or `Standard`.

Is this a feature that has been removed from Craft in v2.5+? I currently have a ton of content that relies on custom HTML outside of what's available in the format bar, so this would be pretty devastating.

Am I overlooking where this option is now?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> If your Redactor config included an "html" value in the "buttons" array, you can remove that, and add a "source" value to the "plugins" array instead.

https://craftcms.com/help/redactor-ii-configs

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Fixed the problem.. Life saver!

Answer (score 0):

It may not be that simple. Redactor have changed the way text is formatted in text fields. Read this blog post on their website to see how they have become evangelical about cleaning up HTML on text areas https://imperavi.com/blog/redactor-superior-in-every-way/

It looks like it may retrospectively remove custom HTML.

Answer (score 0):

redactor still strips any html I added if I go back and make changes through the WYSIWYG side, which means all editing has to be done through HTML. Definitely not a solution, but it's the only way I've been able to edit image size/alignment (which is another feature they apparently removed in redactor 2).

Comment: You definitly do not need to add the "source" plugin manually!

Comment: *edit* You're right, I was being dumb :)

Comment: Well, Craft 2.5 already includes the plugin for you. It's in the app folder and ready for use! https://github.com/pixelandtonic/Craft-Release/tree/master/app/resources/lib/redactor/plugins